# Inconsistent/jagged outline(?)

Tags: rendering, shaders, freestyle, outliner, npr

I'm working on something and I want to make a jagged outline similar to the outline of this 3d model. Preferably it'll change its jagged-ness each frame and it'll only encompass the exterior of the model. Credit to ducklyarts for this image. [image: Credit to ducklyarts]

Any help would be absolutely appreciated!

Comment: I think that these effects are better handled after rendering in Photoshop for instance.